# How can I set up EF codefirst to not create foreign key for specific column that is not actually foreign key

Tags: c#, orm, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am switching my existing project from EDMX to CodeFirst, and I am stuck with what seems to me very simple, but I cant seem to find a solution.

I have an entity (Settings) with a property called 'Group' which is NOT a Foreign Key, and I have not set it up as so.

I also have another entity (ItemsGroups) which id is IdGroup, and those 2 entities should not be connected via Foreign Key.

Then, when I query 'Settings' I get [ItemGroup_IdGroup] column generated.

How Can I tell EF not to generate this column?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property as nullable so that would not impact on the relation between two entities.

```
  [ForeignKey("Group")]
  public int? IdGroup { get; set; }
```

For other, solution you need to remove that attribute manually.

Comment: It's a key, I can't set it as nullable and also i cant remove it :(

Comment: You can add drop constraint in DbMigration class in Up() method to apply changes by sql("Query") method.

also refer below link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#customizing

Comment: thanx, but i dont this this is a migration issue

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my question.

It was, as usual, my error. I added a property in principal class (but in another file as partial, and it was there before I switched to Code First, in my defense) and named it poorly so Entity Framework picked it up and tried to create a foreign key. I just made it a function and no harm done.

But still, I would have like an attribute or something in dependant class so i can mark a property "OK I am not a part of any relationship, don't try anything with me".

Regards,